# Delphi Kiosk mode template issue with C++ Builder (can find xml)

Tags: android, c++, delphi, resources, kiosk

I could desperately use some help with finding out why Embarcadero's [Android Kiosk Lock mode template](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/easily-deploy-advanced-android-kiosk-mode-with-this-firemonkey-template/) is having issues deploying.  I have C++ Builder 11.0 Alexandria, moved PAS files over and compiles and links.  However, when I deploy per Embarcadero directions, I get this error.

> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312
> C:\Users\rodge\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\fun\Source\Android\Debug\Kiosk\AndroidManifest.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/device_owner_receiver').

Stock `Android.manifest.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.embarcadero.Kiosk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="Kiosk" 
        android:debuggable="true" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">

        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
         This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
            android:label="Kiosk"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:lockTaskMode="always">

            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="Kiosk" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" 
  />

        <receiver android:name="com.kiosk.app.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
        <receiver
            android:name="com.kiosk.admin.AdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_owner_receiver"/>

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

The stock `device_owner_reciever.xml` file contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password/>
        <watch-login/>
        <reset-password/>
        <force-lock/>
        <wipe-data/>
        <expire-password/>
        <encrypted-storage/>
        <disable-camera/>
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

I have tried adding to resource and as a file.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds like something you should be asking Embarcadero Support about.

Comment: Thank you Remy.

Answer (score 0):

you must add the resource to the deployment

1. press Project - Deployment
2. select configuration (release/debug)
3. press Add Files and find the file: device_owner_receiver.xml (you find it in xml folder)

the result should be:

```
   local path = xml\
   local name = device_owner_reciver.xml
   remote path = res\xml
   remote name = device_owner_reciver.xml
```